# Разные значения sizeof

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int K[5];
    TEST(K);
    printf("!2>%d<2!", sizeof(K));
}



int TEST(int Tester[])
{
    printf("!1>%d<1!\n", sizeof(Tester));
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SkegAzpVtH
Почему выходят разные значения sizeof

Я новичок в этом языке, не злитесь..

Comment: 1. Вы вызываете необъявленную функцию. 2. Функция `TEST` требует параметр типа `int`. Вы передаете `int *`. Это некомпилируемо в принципе. Вы проигнорировали соответствующие диагностические сообщения компилятора. Не надо игнорировать диагностические сообщения компилятора.

Comment: А разве пять чисел не в пять раз больше одного числа?

Comment: Случайно...
Тут исправленный вариант
https://onlinegdb.com/BJEJVpNYS
ps скобки не помогают

Comment: По прежнему вызывается необъявленная функция.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае `sizeof` применен к объекту типа массив `int [5]`. В втором случае `sizeof` применен к объект типа указатель `int *`. Нет ничего необычного в том, что размер массива отличается от размера указателя.

P.S. Результат `sizeof` нельзя печатать через формат `%d`. Результат `sizeof` печатают через формат `%zu`.

Comment: Можете привести пример рабочего вариант пожалуйста?

Comment: Что такое "рабочий вариант"?

Comment: Где числа совпадут

Comment: Не понял.  Печатайте сами везде `42` - вот они и совпадут. Из параметра типа `int *` невозможно определить исходный размер массива.